# I have question in SQL where I need to order by firstname but problem is I need to order by lastname if Firstname are same

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I need to print the Firstname and LastName of Customers whose FirstName consists of the letter C and LastName consists of the letter E. Also I need to order output in alphabetical order of FirstName. For Customers with same FirstName, have to order such rows in alphabetical order of LastName.

I was able to select firstname and last name and then find firstname if contains letter c and lastname if contains letters e and also able to sort by firstname by writing the below query
**select FirstName, LastName from Customers where FirstName like "%c%" and LastName like "%e%" order by FirstName;**

**But I have a problem here where I got few names in firstname are SAME so at those cases, I need to order by lastname**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order by firstname and then by lastname if the firstname is the same, you can use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
ORDER BY firstname ASC, lastname ASC;
```

Comment: I never thought this would be so simple, thank you so much, it worked